# Categorical Quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm pretty sure I've done this correctly but I just want to make sure:

I'm trying to work out the categorical quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $G$ where $G = k^*$ acts on $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $t\cdot (x,y) = (tx,y)$. I know that any function $F: \mathbb{A}^3 \to X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ must be of the form $(g_1(y), \ldots, g_n(y))$ since the components must be invariant under changes in $x$.

But then it seems like $F:(x,y) \mapsto (y)$ is the categorical quotient?

The only reason this confuses me is that I'm then asked to find a map from $\mathbb{A}^1$ into the catgorical quotient explicitly, so it seems as though I've done something wrong here.

If anyone could point out a mistake in my argument that would be great, then I can try to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the categorical quotient is $\mathbb A^1$. Quite possibly, there is a (Freudian) typo in your assignment and they are really asking you to give a map from $\mathbb A^2$ into the categorical quotient explicitly.

I do not quite understand your reasoning, so here's my argument for why the quotient is as you claim:

The orbit of $(x,y)\in\mathbb A^2$ under this action of $G$ is clearly equal to $G \times\{ y\}$ if $x\ne 0$ and it is equal to $(0,y)$ if $x=0$. In particular, the only closed orbits of the action are the points $(0,y)$ for $y\in\mathbb A^1$. Thus, the closed orbits are parametrized by $\mathbb A^1$ itself. Hence, it seems reasonable that the second projection $\pi\colon\mathbb A^2\to\mathbb A^1$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto y$ is a categorical quotient.

Let's check it. Assume that $\varphi\colon\mathbb A^2 \to X$ is any $G$-invariant morphism. Define $\psi\colon\mathbb A^1\to X$ via $\psi(x):=\varphi(0,x)$. This is certainly a morphism. We have to show that $\psi\circ\pi=\varphi$. Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb A^2$. If $x=0$, then certainly $\psi(\pi(0,y))=\psi(y)=\varphi(0,y)$. If $x\ne 0$, then at least we know $p:=\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(t,y)$ for every $t\in G$ because $\varphi$ is $G$-invariant. Consider $\varphi^{-1}(p)$: It is a closed set. We know $G\times\{y\}\subseteq \varphi^{-1}(p)$. But then, the closure of $G\times\{ y\}$ must also be contained in $\varphi^{-1}(p)$, in particular $\varphi(0,y)=p$.

Comment: Great, thanks very much!